# Get \t (tab) seperated chars into a new column vector

Tags: string, matlab, vector, tabs, reshape

**Background**

I have a char array of Hex values that looks like this:

```
FF23    0008    FF58    00DE    00FC    0008
FF23    0008    FF58    00DF    0012    000C
FF23    0008    FF58    00DD    00F9    000C
FF23    0008    FF58    00DB    00F1    000B
....etc....
```

The separations there are \t (tabs). I managed to massage the char array to get the newlines to be new rows (i.e. `size(string) = numOfRows, 1`).

I need to get them into their own columns of 4 so that I can plot the values. Yes, `hex2dec` is my aim, but it will not deal with the tabs for now.

**Question**

Given the above char array, how do I get each of the groups of 4 chars into their own columns? I can take out the tabs and use a different delimiter, if need be.

**My poor attempts**

```
xlsread('C:\somefile', charArray)
```

This doesn't work for me, as I do not have Office on my Computer, only LibreOffice (http://tinyurl.com/kecqeg6).

I tried:

```
reshape(charArray, length(charArray), 6)
```

But this returns:

```
??? Error using ==> reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.
```

Which I understand, but come on. `reshape()` kinda implies that you can do this stuff.

Thank you for any and all help. I appreciate it.

**EDIT**

Before I thought I have a vector of strings, not a char array. I have updated the post to reflect this. Thank you again.

Comment: What is with the picture linked by the tinyurl.com URL?

Comment: Humor. I get flak all the time from people for not just buying Office and sticking with LibreOffice. This was an attempt to keep the conversation moving. Evidently, I failed.

Comment: Did you try using `C = strsplit(str,'\t')`? on each row? Then accessing a column is trivial.

Comment: Yes, I'll edit my post above to reflect my new understanding, but when I do `class(strVector(1,1))` I get `char` not `string` so the `strsplit()` has no idea what to do with it. Thank you for the idea though

Comment: Jigg, I have tried the `strsplit()` method, unfortunately, I do not have a version of MatLab that includes that method. Thank you. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
A = ['FF23 0008 FF58 00DE 00FC 0008'
     'FF23 0008 FF58 00DF 0012 000C']; %// example data (char array)

B = regexprep(mat2cell(A,ones(1,size(A,1)),size(A,2)),'\s',''); %// get rid of \t
B = vertcat(B{:}) - '0'; %// turn B into a numeric matrix...
ind = B>=17;
B(ind) = B(ind) - 7; %// ... with values 0--15
B = reshape(permute(B,[2 3 1]),4,[],size(A,1)); %// reshape to make groups of 4
result = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times, B, 16.^(3:-1:0).'))).' %// convert each group
```

With the example `A`, this gives

```
result =
       65315           8       65368         222         252           8
       65315           8       65368         223          18          12
```

Comment: Yes, this is great! Thank you a ton! It'll give me a great start on the rest of this.

Answer (score 0):

Converting a text file into a char array is an unnecessary step. You can work directly from the text file.

```
fid = fopen('test.txt','r');    %read text file
C = textscan(fid,'%s%s%s%s%s%s', 'delimiter',' \t','MultipleDelimsAsOne',1);   % 6 cols of chars
fclose(fid)

D = hex2dec(vertcat(C{:}));     % convert cells in strings, concatenate, then convert in doubles
D = reshape(D, numel(D)/6, 6);  % reshape the matrix
```

Comment: This would be great if I had a text file that was like this. The actual data i get from the sensor is just a huge string of Hex values without separators. Thank you for this though! I suppose I can read my cell vector into a temp file and then use your method. Thank you!